# Obtener la diferencia de minutos entre los valores de 2 controles DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, datepicker

Intento obtener la diferencia de minutos en un `TextBox` con dos controles *DateTimePicker*.

Al compilar el programa por primera vez me muestra un número muy largo, luego al cambiar la hora en el control, sí me muestra la hora.

Este código lo estoy ejecutando en el evento `ValueChanged` de cada *DateTimePicker*. Es decir, se encuentra tal cual en cada uno de los 2 eventos, pero es extraño porque sólo pasa cuando lo ejecuto inicialmente.

```
DateTime horaInicio = dtpHorainicial.Value;
DateTime horaFinal = dtpHorafinal.Value;

// A la hora final le restamos la hora de inicio
TimeSpan diferencia = horaFinal.Subtract(horaInicio);

// Mostramos la diferencia en un control TextBox
txt_tiempoTotal.Text = $"{diferencia.TotalMinutes} Minutos";
```

Comment: En el `ValueChanged`de que `DatetimePicker`? En el de los dos? es posible que cuando se carga el valor del primero el segundo todavía no tenga valor o tenga como valor `DateTime.MinValue` y por eso te pasa. Pon un breakpoint en ese código, mira a ver que valores tienen los `DatetimePicker` la primera vez que se llega a ese código, y tendrás que controlar que los valores sean correctos.

Comment: Lo estoy realizando en el ValueChanged de cada DatatimePicker, el código que ves ahí, se encuentra tal cual en cada uno de ellos, pero es extraño porque solo pasa cuando lo ejecuto inicialmente.

Comment: Hola Mauricio. Vuelve a leer el comentario de @Pikoh. La explicación está allí.

Comment: @Mariano la pregunta está en espera, asi que no es posible. De todas maneras con el comentario debería bastarle para solucionarlo :)

Comment: @Mariano si, tienes razón. Efectivamente, puse comentario porque la pregunta tal como está planteada no es muy clara y falta información. He nominado la pregunta para reabrirla y si es así añadiré mi comentario como respuesta.

Comment: Estoy mirando y el DateTimePicker por defecto se inicializa con la fecha actual. Asi que el problema del OP tiene que ser que está inicializando esos campos manualmente

Comment: Es útil la respuesta de Pikoh, en realidad eso es lo que pasa después de hacer el Breakpoint, pero no sé de qué manera inicializar el DatetimePicker para poder hacer la operación que requiero.

Answer (score 0):

¿Querés la diferencia de tiempo entre los dos, expresada en minutos?, ¿o querés la diferencia entre los minutos de un datetimepicker y el otro?

Ejemplo:

- dtp1 : 10:30hs
- dtp2: 0:30hs

La diferencia en minutos es 600; mientras que la diferencia entre los minutos de cada dtp es 0.

Si es la primera opción, seguiría el comentario que te hicieron, de verificar los valores que le están llegando a las variables `horaInicio` y `horaFinal`.

Si es la segunda opción, entonces pódes hacer este calculo:

```
int diferencia = horaFinal.Minute - horaInicio.Minute
```

*(si te da un valor negativo, la diferencia es a favor de la `horaInicio`)*.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Juan Francisco. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Para futuras respuestas, te recomiendo leer [cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Comment: Amigo, gracias por responder. Yo quiero que arroje la diferencia de horas pero representada en minutos, entre los dos datatimepicker, por ejemplo:

       
  - dtp1 10:00am
  - dtp2 11:00am
  - text   60 Minutos

  - dtp1 10:00am
  - dtp2 11:30am
  - text   90 Minutos

En cualquier de las fos formas debería funcionar. Gracias